# Rails route to correct :id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm new to Rails and I'm working through a simple app that has the following routes:

```
 resources :mothers do
    resources :kids
end
```

On the kids show.html.erb page, I'm displaying the mother of the kid and have a link that links back to the mother:

```
 Mother: <%= @kid.mother.full_name %>
      <%= link_to raw('View'), mother_path %>
```

However, this seems to redirect to a path mother/:id where :id is the :id of mother is actually the :id of kid.

How do I correct the route so that it links to the proper mother of the child via the ID?

I've tried

```
<%= link_to raw('View'), mother_path(mother) %>
```

and it says "undefined local variable or method." Am I missing something in my controller?

Comment: undefined local variable or method what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<%= link_to 'View', mother_path(@kid.mother) %>
```

or

```
<%= link_to 'View', @kid.mother %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to read [ruby on rails3 basic routing](http://jonathanhui.com/ruby-rails-3-routing) by which you will get a basic idea of routing to work properly

Comment: Thanks! this is the tutorial i'm looking for!

Answer (score 0):

No need to have one resource into the other.

**Kid Model**

```
class Kid < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :mother
end
```

**Mother Model**

```
class Mother < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :kids
end
```

**Your routes.rb-**

```
resources :mothers 

 resources :kids
```

**Your view Link:**

```
<%= link_to 'View', {:controller => 'mother', :action => :show, :id => @kid.mother.id} %>
```